# Difference of providing a -Command "& {...}" to -Command "{...} - they seem to do the same thing

Tags: powershell

I need to kill a (maybe respawning) program if found in a timeframe for about 2 minutes.

What is the difference between

```
Powershell.exe -Command "& {for ($i=1; $i -le 1200; $i++) 
                         { Stop-Process -Name ExecuteableName.exe -Force  2>&1|out-null; 
                           Start-Sleep -m 100; }}"
```

and

```
Powershell.exe -Command "for ($i=1; $i -le 1200; $i++) 
                         { Stop-Process -Name ExecuteableName.exe -Force  2>&1|out-null; 
                           Start-Sleep -m 100; }"
```

(omitted `-executionpolicy remotesigned` for brevity from both calls)? I am *not* inside the PS shell, but using the "normal" CMD.exe or a TCC/LE (jpsoftware)-shell.

If I replace the `Stop-Process` with some output (or remove the outputstream redirect), both seem to be identical - but *powershell.exe /help* suggests to use the & variant.

I read through [powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) and  [microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#call-operator-)

but did not get it. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between ...?

In this case, they're are functionally identical. There's a couple of points you'll need to understand to know the exact difference.

The first is the [`-Command` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe#-command). This can be either: `-`, a string, or a ScriptBlock.

Ignoring `-` as it's just one of the other two, but from standard input rather than an argument. A string is the easiest to understand as it's simply PowerShell code (both your examples use a string parameter). A ScriptBlock however, only exists as a type in PowerShell:

> The Command parameter only accepts a script block for execution when it can recognize the value passed to Command as a ScriptBlock type. This is only possible when running PowerShell.exe from another PowerShell host.

You don't mention the shell you're using to call `Powershell.exe`, but it's likely not PowerShell, so using a ScriptBlock will not be possible. For Example:

```bsh
PS> Powershell.exe -Command {Write-Host 'Hello world!'}
Hello world!
```

---

The second point to understand is what a ScriptBlock is. There's documentation for it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks), but I personally didn't find it very helpful for understanding the nuances.
It might be easier to grasp if you assign the ScriptBlock to a variable.

```bsh
PS> $block = {Write-Host 'Hello world!'}
PS> & $block
Hello world!
```

While ScriptBlocks are useful, in this case (and your first example), there's no benefit over the more simple

```bsh
PS> Write-Host 'Hello world!'
Hello world!
```

---

> but *powershell.exe /help* suggests to use the & variant

I'm not sure where you're reading, but it's most likely just describing how to avoid this situation:

> You can write a script block inside the string, but instead of being executed it will behave exactly as though you typed it at a typical PowerShell prompt, printing the contents of the script block back out to you.

Which would be similar to

```bsh
PS> $block = {Write-Host 'Hello world!'}
PS> $block
Write-Host 'Hello world!'
```